# Integrating MBProgressHUD with two classes

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

Im am trying to properly integrate MBProgressHUD in a project while i am downloading and processing some data. Forgive me my ignorance if i am asking stupid things, but i'm a complete noob...

I have a "Data" class that is handling my HTTPRequests, so i thing here is the proper place to put some stuff in:

```
-(void)resolve
{
    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self url]]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSLog(@"Resolving content from: %@",[self url]);
    // create the connection with the request
    // and start loading the data
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) {
        // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
        // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Content - resolve: connection failed");
    }

    // Here is the part that it makes me crazy...

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES] retain];

    return;

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // This method is called when the server has determined that it
    // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse.

    // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
    // redirect, so each time we reset the data.

    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    expectedLength = [response expectedContentLength];
    currentLength = 0;
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    currentLength += [data length];
    HUD.progress = currentLength / (float)expectedLength;

    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.

    [receivedData appendData:data];
    return;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [HUD hide:YES];
    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    [receivedData release];

    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Content - Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    return;
}
```

Now i know that putting the "showHUDaddedTo" in the -(void)resolve is not the right way...

I am calling this data function from a view controller with an IBaction like this:

```
-(IBAction) btnClicked:(id) sender {
    if ([[issue status] intValue] == 1 ) // issue is not downloaded
    {

        [(Content *)[issue content] resolve];
        //HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES] retain];




    }
    else // issue is downloaded - needs to be archived
    {
        NSError * error = nil;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[(Content *)[issue content] path]  error:&error];
        if (error) {
            // implement error handling

        }
        else {
            Content * c = (Content *)[issue content];
            [c setPath:@""];
            [issue setStatus:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
            [buttonView setTitle:@"Download" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [gotoIssue setTitle:@"..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            // notify all interested parties of the archived content
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"contentArchived" object:self]; // make sure its persisted!

        }



    }
}
```

Simply said: i would like to call all the MBProgressHUD stuff from my Conten.m file in the moment i push the download button in my IssueController.m file. I think you see now where my problem is: i am not a coder ;-) Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,

sandor

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use the HUD method showWhileExecuting. Wrap your calls up in a new method and call that to download your information. When your method finishes, so will your HUD.

Also, is there a reason why you are retaining your calls for the HUD? I have not seen that before and I'm not sure if you need to retain those as they are autoreleased.

Comment: Thnks Bill, i'll try to do what you are suggesting. Reatining: i was using this code snippet from the inititial documentation and examples they are coming with the HUD project "HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES] retain];" - As i said: i am not a coder, so maybe i'm doing foolish things sometimes :-)

Comment: No, that is definitely one way to do it. I found it to be a little harder work with vs the -showWhileExecuting, but they both certainly work. Hopefully you can get it working the way you need.